# Can Excel scatter chart background colours be customized based on data values?

Tags: excel, vba, plot

I have a 5row x 2col table. There are 5 data points, each with a corresponding X and Y value. The X,Y values are used to plot a scatter plot.

I want to **customize the background** of the scatter plot **as a function of the data points itself**, i.e., the X and Y extents of the coloured rectangles should be in my control. Ideally I would like the median X and Y values from the data to make the X and Y "axes" respectively, which are the boundaries of the different coloured rectangles.

[image]

Currently I have chosen the "Shape Fill" -> "Picture" option while formatting the Chart area. The picture is currently created manually in MS Powerpoint, with the same aspect ratio as the chart area.

Example VBA code. It takes data from a 5x2 table present in the range A2:B6 in "Sheet1".

```vb
Sub scatter_plot_simple()
    Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Values"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!C$2:$C$6"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you creating the picture that you use as the background? That is what you would need to automate.

Comment: So, how do you create the picture we can see in your question?

Comment: Here you are asking about two mutually exclusive alternatives. First, background of the scatter plot as a function of the data points itself. Second, the X and Y extents of the coloured rectangles should be in your control. How can both these be done simultaneously. Either the first could be done automatically with some criteria which you haven't mentioned or the second one which you are already doing. Also, the chart area looks absolutely white, the plot area seems to have those colors. Explain how you are doing it so someone can help with vba

Comment: @JohnColeman The picture is a saved image created manually in MS Powerpoint, with the same aspect ratio as the chart area. Then I use the "Shape Fill" option -> "Picture" sub-option, manually, in the Excel chart.

Comment: @FaneDuru The picture is a saved image created manually in MS Powerpoint, with the same aspect ratio as the chart area. Then I use the "Shape Fill" option -> "Picture" sub-option, manually, in the Excel chart.

Comment: @Naresh The background of the VBA generated chart looks white because I haven't added any background. However, I would like to include a background based on a grid created by 2 values, the median of the X data values (which becomes the vertical separation) and the median of the Y data values (horizontal separation). So, both the background and the rectangles are the same thing, essentially.

Comment: @Naresh The Chart Crosshair Cursor looks interesting! Thank you! However, would you know a way to colour the 4 rectangular "sections" thus made (around the cursor) with different colours?

Comment: In that case, instead of 2 lines you need 2 rectangles with different colored background link in your image. Keep the background light green and then add two rectangles one vertical (light red) and another horizontal (light Blue) with transparency 50%. So, it will look like 4 rectangles.

Comment: I cannot understand the logic of creating the red/brown rectangle width... I must leave the office in some minutes. I will paste a piece of code showing one of the way to accomplish your task. It will create only the left part, all rectangles being colored the same, let us say, green. The rest must be calculated, but it is possible do do that. I will also try this part, if the proposed solution looks convenient for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

"It's just basic math" so the code is not commented...  ;-)

**EDIT**: moved the chart to a worksheet and the shapes are just plotted behind the (transparent) chart.  Turn off gridlines on the worksheet or they'll show through...

```vb
Sub scatter_plot_simple()
    Const CHT_NAME As String = "QUADRANTS"
    Dim cht As Chart, rngX As Range, rngY As Range, wsData As Worksheet, co
    Dim medX, medY, wsChart As Worksheet
    
    Set wsChart = Worksheets("Chart")
    Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")
    Set rngX = wsData.Range("B2:B400")
    Set rngY = wsData.Range("C2:C400")
    
    DeleteAllShapes wsChart
    
    'hosting the chart on a worksheet...
    Set co = wsChart.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter)
    co.Name = CHT_NAME
    co.Fill.Visible = msoFalse 'no background
    co.Top = 10
    co.Left = 10
    co.Width = 400
    co.Height = 400
    
    Set cht = co.Chart
    ClearSeries cht    'make sure no "auto-plotted" series
    With cht
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Data"
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rngX
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngY
        .PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse 'no background
    End With
    
    medX = Application.Median(rngX)
    medY = Application.Median(rngY)
    
    AddQuadrants cht, medX, medY
    
End Sub

Sub AddQuadrants(cht As Chart, medX, medY)
 
    Dim minX, maxX, minY, maxY, xAxis As Axis, yAxis As Axis
    Dim xSpan, ySpan, shp1, Q1 As Shape, Q2 As Shape, Q3 As Shape, Q4 As Shape
    Dim Q1W, Q1H, ws As Worksheet, co As Object, posTop As Long, posleft As Long
    
    Set co = cht.Parent 'chartobject (a container for the chart when hosted on a worksheet)
    Set ws = co.Parent  'the hosting worksheet
    
    Set xAxis = cht.Axes(xlCategory)
    Set yAxis = cht.Axes(xlValue)
    
    minX = xAxis.MinimumScale
    maxX = xAxis.MaximumScale
    xSpan = maxX - minX
    
    minY = yAxis.MinimumScale
    maxY = yAxis.MaximumScale
    ySpan = maxY - minY
    
    Q1W = ((medX - minX) / xSpan) * xAxis.Width
    Q1H = ((maxY - medY) / ySpan) * yAxis.Height
    
    posTop = 4 + co.Top + yAxis.Top     'fudging this a bit...
    posleft = 4 + co.Left + xAxis.Left  'fudging this a bit...
    
    Set Q1 = Quadrant(ws, posleft, posTop, Q1W, Q1H, vbYellow)
    Set Q2 = Quadrant(ws, posleft + Q1W, posTop, xAxis.Width - Q1W, Q1H, vbRed)
    Set Q3 = Quadrant(ws, posleft, posTop + Q1H, Q1W, yAxis.Height - Q1H, vbBlue)
    Set Q4 = Quadrant(ws, posleft + Q1W, posTop + Q1H, _
                      xAxis.Width - Q1W, yAxis.Height - Q1H, vbGreen)
    
End Sub

Function Quadrant(ws As Worksheet, l, t, w, h, clr As Long) As Shape
    Dim rv As Shape
    Set rv = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, l, t, w, h)
    rv.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = clr
    rv.Fill.Transparency = 0.9
    rv.Fill.Solid
    rv.Line.Visible = False
    rv.ZOrder msoSendToBack
    Set Quadrant = rv
End Function

Sub ClearSeries(cht As Chart)
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
End Sub

Sub DeleteAllShapes(ws As Worksheet)
    Do While ws.Shapes.Count > 0
       ws.Shapes(1).Delete
    Loop
End Sub
```

Or with no VBA: https://peltiertech.com/excel-chart-with-colored-quadrant-background/

Comment: I was simply amazed at how quickly you responded with such a helpful piece of code, @Tim Williams. This is my first question in StackOverFlow, and I have to admit that I am simply overwhelmed by the responses from such kind (and skilled) people who help out random strangers this way. Thank you so very much!

Comment: By the way, do you have any ideas about how to get the shapes behind the plotted XY scatter? It would be nice to be able to hover over any data point to see all the values. I did add data-labels, so it looks okay, but it would be better if I could see the data points and labels in full color (and not faded behind the coloured rectangles).

Comment: If you want the shapes behind the chart then you need to add them either to the worksheet (if using an embedded chart) or to an empty chart sheet before adding the chart.  Then set the chart fill to "none" so that the shapes can be seen behind the chart.  I will maybe take a look later if I can modify my code to do that...

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next piece of code. It will create rectangles, color them, group, export the group picture and add it as plotter area user picture. No time to comment the code. If not clear, I will comment in in some hours, when I will be at home:

```
Sub scatter_plot_simple()
    Dim sC As Chart, sh As Worksheet, Chart1 As Chart, sGr As Shape, s As Shape, s1 As Shape, s2 As Shape
    Dim pltH As Double, pltW As Double, pltAH As Double, pltAW As Double, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim maxX As Long, maxY As Long, majUnitY As Long, topS As Double, leftS As Double
    
    majUnitY = 20 'major unity for X axes
    'delete the previous chart (used for testing)
    For Each sC In Charts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            If sC.Name = "MyChart" Then sC.Delete: Exit For
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .Name = "MyChart"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Values"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & sh.Name & "!B2:B6"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & sh.Name & "!C2:C6"
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = majUnitY
        maxX = .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale             'maximum scale of X axes
        pltAH = .PlotArea.height: pltAW = .PlotArea.width 'plot area height
        maxY = .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale                'maximum scale of X axes
        'extract dimensions of the future rectangles to be created:
        pltH = .PlotArea.height / maxY: pltW = .PlotArea.width / (maxX / majUnitY)
    End With
    'create the rectangle equal to chart Plot area:
    Set s = sh.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, pltAW, pltAH)
    s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'white color
    topS = 0: leftS = 0
    Dim maxGreen As Long  ' variable to be used to change the rectangle colors
    maxGreen = 2
    'create the necessary colored rectangles to reflect the maximum X and maximum Y
    For j = 1 To maxX / majUnitY
        For i = 1 To 6
            Set s1 = sh.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, leftS, topS, pltW, pltH)
            With s1
                .Select
                'color rectangles according to their position:
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(6 - i >= maxGreen, IIf(j = 1, RGB(201, 163, 102), RGB(138, 197, 139)), IIf(j = 1, RGB(231, 157, 126), RGB(145, 208, 215)))
                .line.Weight = 2
                .line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End With
            If i = 1 And j = 1 Then  'group the big rectangle (plot area dimensions) with the first rectangle
                Set sGr = sh.Shapes.Range(Array(s.Name, s1.Name)).Group
            Else
                'group the previous group with the created rectangle
                Set sGr = sh.Shapes.Range(Array(sGr.Name, s1.Name)).Group
            End If
            topS = topS + pltH  'increment Top position for the future rectangle
        Next i
        'adding the rectangles slices over the existing rectangles in second column:
        If j = 2 Then
            topS = 0
            For k = 1 To 6
                Set s2 = sh.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, leftS + 2, topS + 2, pltW / 3, pltH - 4)
                With s2
                    .Select
                    If 6 - k >= maxGreen Then
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 163, 102)
                        .line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 163, 102)
                    Else
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(231, 157, 126)
                        .line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(231, 157, 126)
                    End If
                End With
                Set sGr = sh.Shapes.Range(Array(sGr.Name, s2.Name)).Group
                topS = topS + pltH
            Next k
            
        End If
        leftS = leftS + pltW: topS = 0 'increment the left possition and reset the Top poz to zero
    Next j
    'Part of exporting the created group as picture:
    Dim pictPath As String
    pictPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\chartPict.jpg" 'the path where to be saved
    ExportShPict sGr, sh, pictPath                          'export function
    Chart1.PlotArea.Format.Fill.UserPicture pictPath   'place the exported picture to the chart plot area
    sGr.Delete                                                   'delete the helper group
    Chart1.Activate                                            'activate the chart sheet
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Private Sub ExportShPict(s As Shape, sh As Worksheet, pictPath As String)
   Dim ch As ChartObject
   'create a new chart using the shape (group) dimensions
   Set ch = sh.ChartObjects.Add(left:=1, top:=1, width:=100, height:=100)
   ch.width = s.width: ch.height = s.height
   'copy the group picture on the newly created chart
   s.CopyPicture: ch.Activate: ActiveChart.Paste
   'export the chart which practically means only the picture
   ch.Chart.Export FileName:=pictPath, FilterName:="JPG"
   ch.Delete 'delete the helper chart
End Sub
```

I deduced the logic to change colors for the vertical axes, but you did not say anything about the position on X axes, where the down color to be changed. If this aspect is clear, some smaller rectangles can be placed on the second rectangles column.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response despite being busy, @FaneDuru! The positions of the color changes in both X and Y directions is at the median value of the X and Y data respectively. Somehow I wasn't able to get the figure that I expected using your code. Unfortunately I don't know how to attach my figure (with your code) here for your reference.